# AlertDialog In MVVM

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-alertdialog, android-mvvm

I am building an app in MVVM pattern and I am using 3 different styles of dialogs(some of them have 2 buttons,some of them 3).
Since the AlertDialog refers to the view, I wrote the code in the fragment.
I have 3 dialogs in the same fragment and its look kind of messy.

My questions:

- Is this a good practice to use the dialogs code in the fragment itself, like I did in the first place?
- Is there anyway to make it clearer ?
- Is there any way I make the dialog code shorter? So I don't have to write the same code over and over? (Reminder: I am using 3 different styles of dialogs)

This is the code for one of the dialogs:

```
        AlertDialog optionsDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext()).create();
        View dialogView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tasks_long_click_options_design, null);
        optionsDialog.setView(dialogView);

        optionsDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)); // Transparent Corners

        Button editButton = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTaskButton);
        Button deleteButton = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.deleteTaskButton);
        Button cancelButton = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.cancelTaskButton);

        editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent editTask = new Intent(requireActivity(), AddTaskActivity.class);

                editTask.putExtra("taskName", task.getTaskName());
                editTask.putExtra("taskPriority", task.getTaskPriority());
                editTask.putExtra("taskTag", task.getTaskTag());
                editTask.putExtra("taskDate", task.getTaskDate());
                editTask.putExtra("taskTime", task.getTaskTime());
                editTask.putExtra("taskID", task.getTaskID());

                Log.e("DailyFragment", "Send Task By Intent: Name- " + task.getTaskName() + " Color-" + task.getTaskPriority() + " Tag- " + task.getTaskTag() + " Date- "
                        + task.getTaskDate() + " Time- " + task.getTaskTime());

                optionsDialog.dismiss();
```

The second dialog is with 2 buttons,and the third dialog is with 4.

Thank you !

Comment: You can write somewhere but you need to create listener from this class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Is this a good practice to use the dialogs code in the fragment itself?**
   Yes, the Fragment is a UI layer. It is correct to use an AlertDialog there.
2. **Is there anyway to make it clearer**?
   That completely depends on your implementation, however there is nothing wrong with the current implementation as it is *readable* & quite *understandable*.
3. **Is there any way I make the dialog code shorter?
   So I don't have to write the same code over and over? (Reminder: I am using 3 different styles of dialogs)**
   Yes, if you are using same strategy for dialog creation where only certain styles are different then you can create simple method with relevant parameters like:

```kotlin
fun showDialogWith(style: String) {
    val styleTypeView = when(style) {
        "normal" -> R.layot.normal_dialog
        "info" -> R.layot.info_dialog
        "error" -> R.layot.error_dialog
    }

    layoutInflater.inflate(styleTypeView, null);
    
    /* Handle other theming / operations depending on the view type */
}
```

And call it like:
Normal Dialog - `showDialogWith("normal")`
Info. Dialog - `showDialogWith("info")`
Error Dialog - `showDialogWith("error")`